# Firestore Security Rules: request.time "undefined on object"

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a Security Rule based upon [request.time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time) as given in an example on [AngularFirebase website](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-security-rules-guide/#Time-based-Rules-Examples).

My function is

```
function isThrottled() {
    return request.time < resource.data.lastUpdate + duration.value(1, 'm')
}
```

Where I'm trying to `allow update: if isThrottled() == false`

However, when I try to update a document with this rule, it fails due to **time** being not defined on the object.

> Error: simulator.rules line [169], column [12]. Property time is
>   undefined on object.

Shouldn't every request have a `time` or `TimeStamp` attached to it? Is this something to do with how I'm initializing my Cloud Functions or client app?

Screenshots below:

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

A snippet for the rest of the update security rules are:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{db}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      match /username/{id} {
        allow update: if isSelf(userId)
                      && usernameAvailable(incomingData().username)
                      && incomingData().username is string
                      && incomingData().username.size() <= 25
                      && incomingFields().size() == 1
                      && isThrottled() == false;
      }
    }

    function incomingData() {
      return request.resource.data
    }
    function isThrottled() {
        return request.time < resource.data.lastUpdate + duration.value(1, 'm')
        }
    function incomingFields() {
        return incomingData().keys()
    }
    function isSelf(userId) {
        return userId == currentUser().uid;
    }
    function usernameAvailable(username) {
        return !exists(/databases/$(db)/documents/usernames/$(username));
    }


  }
}
```

The `username` collection is a subcollection under each `user` document (in the `users` root collection. Each `username` document only has 1 field called `username` that users can update).

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire, minimal set of rules that has this problem (not just a screenshot, paste them into the question).

Comment: I updated my question to show you my rules for this specific update check

Answer (score 19):

This might not be useful for your case in particular, but I had the same error when checking a custom claim on the token object.

Before accessing the field you can use `in` to check whether the property exists on the object. This code generates the error if agent is not defined:

```
allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.agent == true;
```

This code works fine if agent is not defined:

```
allow write: if request.auth != null && "agent" in request.auth.token && request.auth.token.agent == true;
```